# Won't compile with Hebrew in the path

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, hebrew, compilation-error

**Description of the problem**
Fails to export to PDF (and other formats) when there is Hebrew in the path.

On Ubuntu 16.04 with LyX 2.3 I get this error message:

[image: The error message in LyX]

On Ubuntu 18.04 with LyX 2.2.3 I get this error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.6.12)  12 JUN 2018 23:20
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**______.tex
(./______.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic/ivritex/cp1255.def
File: cp1255.def 2001/07/22 v1.1a Hebrew input encoding file
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/theorem.sty
Package: theorem 2014/10/28 v2.2c Theorem extension package (FMi)
\theorem@style=\toks16
\theorem@bodyfont=\toks17
\theorempreskipamount=\skip43
\theorempostskipamount=\skip44
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/thp.sty
File: thp.sty 2014/10/28 v2.2c Theorem extension package (FMi)
))
\c@theorem=\count88
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/06/05 3.22 The Babel package
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/06/05 3.22 Babel switching mechanism
)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \heblamed 

l.426       {}}
               %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \hebhet 

l.426       {}}
               %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/06/05 3.22 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count89
\U@D=\dimen103
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count90
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \heblamed 

l.191 \ldf@finish\CurrentOption

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \hebhet 

l.191 \ldf@finish\CurrentOption

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

) (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic/ivritex/rlbabel.def
File: rlbabel.def 2002/12/26 v2.3f Right-to-Left support from the babel system 
Hebrew language support from the babel system
) (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic/ivritex/hebrew.ldf
File: hebrew.ldf 2002/12/26 v2.3f Hebrew language definition from the babel sys
tem Hebrew language support from the babel system

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 71.

\l@hebrew = a dialect from \language0
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \heblamed 

l.331 \ldf@finish{hebrew}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \hebhet 

l.331 \ldf@finish{hebrew}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

)) (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic/ivritex/lheenc.def
File: lheenc.def 1998/01/07 v1.1a 7-bit Hebrew font encoding (test version: sti
ll liable to change)
Now handling font encoding LHE ...
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \heblamed 

l.69 \DeclareFontEncoding{LHE}{}{}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \hebhet 

l.69 \DeclareFontEncoding{LHE}{}{}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LHE
)

! LaTeX Error: Command \heblamed unavailable in encoding T1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.29 \begin{document}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! LaTeX Error: Command \hebhet unavailable in encoding T1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.29 \begin{document}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.29 \begin{document}

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

No file ______.aux.
\openout1 = `______.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LHE/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LHE+cmr on input line 29.
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic/ivritex/lhecmr.fd
File: lhecmr.fd 1998/01/07 v1.1a Hebrew default font (test version: still liabl
e to change)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./____
__.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1295 strings out of 492646
 15505 string characters out of 6129548
 80899 words of memory out of 5000000
 5217 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4623 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,23p,187b,115s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 </home/yitzchak/.texlive2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/hebrew/jerus10
.600pk>{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1
.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.p
fb>
Output written on ______.pdf (1 page, 13739 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 23 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

**Minimal example file**, called א.lyx:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass heb-article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding cp1255
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
א
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

*Installation:*

```
git clone https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu.git
cd install-tl-ubuntu
sudo sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyx-devel/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lyx
```

*LyX app and document setting:*

```
Tools->Prefrences->Keyboard/Mouse:
  Set Hebrew keyboard map
Document->Settings->Document Class:
  Set Hebrew Article as the document class
Document->Settings->Fonts:
  *Do not* check "Use non-Tex fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTex) and leave everything on default
Document->Settings->Language:
  Language: Hebrew
  Encoding: Unicode (ucs-extended)(utf8x) OR Hebrew (CP 1255)
```

*Creating and exporting the file:*

```
Create a file such as ~/Desktop/א/א.lyx (Or you can use the above example file)
Close LyX
Open LyX again and open that file.
Attempt to export or preview using pdflatex
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce, but for me it appears to work fine on Ubuntu 16.04. Here is a screenshot in LyX: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4fh9n6tu9jg5z6/LyX.png?dl=0. As you can see (in the window title), both the directory and the filename itself have Hebrew in it. Here is a screenshot of the produced PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a55qexxfs04u57f/PDF.png?dl=0

Comment: which release of latex do you have? and the error won;t be "weird" it probably helps solve the problem if you show it, please show the full erro from the log in a code (`{}`) section in teh question so line endings are preserved

Comment: Thanks for the help. I hope that now it's more clear and useful.

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example .lyx file? For more information, see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: My minimal example contains a single character in the content. I'd put 0 characters into the document, but then it wouldn't even attempt to print.

Comment: @yman I've tried all kinds of weird paths with Hebrew in the parent directories, and I cannot reproduce the error on 16.04. Your MWE compiles to PDF for me. If you can give me a script where all I have to do is run `sudo ./yourscript`, that runs on a fresh Ubuntu installation, that will allow me to reproduce the problem, I will take a look at it (although possibly not for some time). For example, in your script you can use `install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew` if that makes it easier. Otherwise, I don't think I can help. Sorry for this problem. It must be very annoying!

Comment: I think I know why. Earlier I tried using non-Latex fonts, but no font I tried worked. However this time I actually noticed in the [wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/HebrewOnLinux) that FreeFonts are supposed to work, so I finally tried it and they do, so long as I export with XeTeX, even when there is Hebrew in the path. Could it be that you're using XeTeX with FreeFonts to export and that's why you don't get the same error as I do?

Thanks for putting in the time trying to help me out. I also re-wrote the question to hopefully make it better organized and clearer.